# What thread will these event callbacks occur on?

Tags: c#, multithreading, visual-studio-2010

```
new System.Threading.Thread(() =>
    {
        var myObject = new CustomObject();
        myObject.SomeEvent += SomeMethod;
    }).Start();
```

**Part 1:** Assume I run the above code on my main UI thread in a winforms applications.  Which `Thread` will calls to `SomeMethod` occur on?  Will they occur on the same `Thread` that was created when I created the object?

**Part 2:** Using Visual Studio 2010, how can I figure this out on my own?  I don't know where you find out what `Thread` something is running on.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The event handler `SomeMethod` will run on whatever thread raised the event.

You can set a breakpoint in the event handler `SomeMethod` and look at the [Threads window](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w15yf86f.aspx) (you will probably want to give your threads meaningful names to find them).

Comment: Ah I see.  So, if I wanted to make sure that `SomeMethod` runs on a new `Thread`, would it be considered good practice to do something like... `new Thread( () => this.SomeEvent.Invoke(this, new EventArgs()) ).Start();` when I want to actually raise the event?

Comment: @michael.mankus, if you want to run the event on a separate thread, use the `BeginInvoke`/`EndInvoke` methods or `Tasks` instead of newing up a `Thread` object. Although, this typically isn't how events are done, it is usually the responsibility of the event handler to do background work if needed, otherwise you risk causing handlers to be reentrant. If you really want your event to be raised automatically in the background, make sure it is clearly documented as such.

Comment: Also check out this eBook specifically about threading in C#: http://www.albahari.com/threading/#_Thread_Pooling

Comment: I see what you mean regarding who typically has the responsibility to do background (threaded) work if needed.  So moving forward, I will invoke the event normally and in the handler I will create a background task if needed.  Makes sense.

Answer (score 2):

To find out which thread you are currently executing in, you can use `Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId`.

To answer your question: SomeMethod will be executed in the thread that raises the event.

In your case, it actually will never be executed as you assign your method to the event but never actually raise the event.

Answer (score 0):

you may check the **ManagedThreadId** Property http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.thread.managedthreadid.aspx

@Mike Here is the sample

```
        Console.WriteLine("Main New Thread : {0}", System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);

        new System.Threading.Thread(() =>
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Inside New Thread : {0}", System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
        }).Start();

        Console.WriteLine("Main New Thread : {0}", System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
```

Comment: This answer was already provided by @Daniel and therefore isn't adding any value.

Answer (score 0):

Just wanted to add a simple test that will allow you to check the thread on which the handler executes:

```
class Test
{
    delegate void update();
    static event update updateEvent;

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Parent thread: " + Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
        updateEvent += new update(Test_updateEvent);
        var t = new Thread(
            () =>
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Child thread: " + Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
                updateEvent();
            });
        t.Start();
        t.Join();
    }

    static void Test_updateEvent()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Event thread: " + Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
    }
}
```

which prints:

```
Parent thread: 1
Child thread: 3
Event thread: 3
```